# Show tooltip of a bottom-level HTML element overlapping with a top-level element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a red alarm image together with the number of alarms I have. The image itself has a tooltip. I need to place the number in the middle of the image. But then my problem is when I place the cursor on the image, the tooltip  won't show because the image is at the bottom-level, partially blocked by the number text. Is there anyway I can make the tooltip work whenever I hover the mouse on any part of the image (including the overlapping text)?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:60px;color:red;" title="The alarm is on!">notifications</i> 
  <div style="position:relative;top:-38px;left:20px"><strong>+2</strong></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Position the parent div relative and then the child div absolute. There are hundred of question on this on SO.

Comment: @Paulie_D if this is a dupe, please flag it, or be more precise with your comment. Simply adding `relative` to the parent div and `absolute` to the child (which one?) won't change anything to the tooltip not showing on the number..

Answer (score 2):

Just add title to the number as well :) Or you can create custom tooltip that will be triggered using JS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:60px;color:red;" title="The alarm is on!">notifications</i> 
  <div title="The alarm is on!" style="position:relative;top:-38px;left:20px"><strong>+2</strong></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have an onlick property for the image. To make sure onlick of the image works, I would have to add that onclick to the text as well using your approach. I am wondering if there is a generic way, so that onclick and tooltip things work

Comment: You should put click on the parent div, that contains both img and number, just set the width so it doesnt take 100%

Comment: Or if you don't want to use the parent div for any reason, you can place a transparent div on top of image and text, and place tooltip and click events on that div.

Comment: But parental div is a rectangle, which covers more area than the children image which is a bell shape. I want the onclick to work on the bell image, not the whole rectangle.

Comment: you can have the same click function on both image and number, just ask if you clicked on number, if yes , trigger the click from bell image